# Bash script for rebooting if string not found in the output of terminal program

Tags: bash, scripting

I came to this site for help in a task I couldn't find an answer for.

I need a script that reboots my computer is a string is not found in the output of a terminal program for, let's say, 30 seconds. That is, if the script doesn't find the name "joe" within 30 seconds, it will trigger the reboot command. Or if you want to look at it from another perspective, the script will reboot the machine unless the name "joe" is found in the output of terminal program within a given time period.

I have very little knowledge of bash scripting. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

malandante

Comment: sounds like a terrible idea. I understand that some dirty jobs are an unavoidable sin but a reboot is usually too much. Is not enough to restart the program? Or if a reboot is needed i suggest the "watchdog" functions

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. You should do some research, give something a go and then come back when you've hit a wall and ask a question that is a [mcve]. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

### Use Expect

Use Expect rather than Bash to manage interactive scripts, or when you need to treat standard output as a stream.

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect

set timeout 30
spawn /path/to/script.sh
expect {
    joe {}

    # assumes current user has passwordless access to the reboot
    # command as configured in /etc/sudoers
    timeout { exec /usr/bin/sudo /sbin/reboot } 
}
```

If you can reliably treat standard output from your script in a line-oriented fashion then you can use the Bash *TMOUT* variable to set a timeout on your *read* command, but there are a number of ways this can fail. Expect is really the right tool for the job.